# Subalgebras of $B(H)$ consisting of all operators leaving a given finite dimensional space invariant

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, kt.k-theory-and-homology, c-star-algebras

Let $H$ be an infinite dimensional separable Hilbert space. Let $V$ be a finite dimensional subspace of $H$.
Put $$A=\{T\in B(H)\mid T(V)\subseteq V\}.$$

So $A$ is a Banach algebra.

Can we equip $A$ with an involution $*$ such that we get a $C^*$ algebra structure on $A$?

What are K-groups of $A$ as a Banach algebra?

Comment: @MarkSapir Then $A= B(H)$ which is an obvious $C^*$-algebra?

Comment: @MarkSapir I do not care this case since the answer is obvious.

Comment: @MarkSapir But if we allow H to be a finite dim space the answer to the first question is negative for ex" dim H=2 and dim V=1 . We get the three dimensional algebra isomorphic to upper triangle matrices. It can not become a C^* algebra.

Comment: Whenever nontrivial, your $A$ is not semi-simple and hence cannot be a C*-algebra.

Comment: @NarutakaOZAWA I was aware of this fact for commutative Banach algebra(May be a corollary ir an exercize in Rudin Book) but what is the statement for noncommutative case? BTW what can be said about k groups of this algebra)

Comment: @NarutakaOZAWA Thank you for your interesting comment. I guess that the maximal left ideal your are indicating to is the left ideal of all operatores vanishing at V.

Comment: @NarutakaOZAWA  Yes I can see the reason now. One define a morphism from $A$ to $L(V)$ by restriction. But the jacobson radical of L(V) is zero. its premimage is the ideal I mentioned. But what about K-groups?